# WPF MVVM - Shared data object all over the ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm, properties

I build an application that the user have to login in order to continue.

The user that has been connected, assigned into CurrentAccountProperty in the current ViewModel.

Now, How do I make this current connected account accessible to all the other ViewModels that have interaction with it and its data?

For example, ViewModels that manipulate its login details, ViewModels, for example, that add somthing to its  RecentActivities property and so on..

Should I hold a reference to the current account? somthing like CurrentAccount in each ViewModel that uses this object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I usually `Export`(MEF) property I set after user is logged in.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets LoggedUser.
    /// </summary>
    [Export]
    public UserInfo LoggedUser { get; set; }
```

Then I `Import` everywhere I need access to logged user.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets LoggedUser.
    /// </summary>
    [Import]
    public UserInfo LoggedUser { get; set; }
```

Of course you can use any IoC container as well. And you should use some kind of IoC when you talk about MVVM.

Comment: Sounds good.. I'll try this. Thanks.
BTW, holding reference from one VM to another is a bad idea? Is it violate the MVVM pattern?

Comment: No problem, always glad to help. ...since you many times need to access ViewModels which should be common for more views there is no problem hold a reference to another ViewModel. It's not violation of MVVM pattern. If you use MEF you can export that ViewModel with CreationPolicy.Shared... if this answers your question mark it as accepted answer please.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with holding a reference to one view model to another. Again however, Viktors way in MEF is equally valid to injecting some other object into the constructor. It might be helpful to also explain that CreationPolicy.Shared means a singleton in MEF

Comment: @TheunculledBadger Nevertheless I would not say It's the same thing. When you inject/import(whatever) that dependency(i.e. Logged user object) using constructor then you make it required. So when you test that view model you have to inject some user object every time even though you test some logic which don't have to know about logged user.

Comment: @TheUnculledBadger But I agree... it does not necessarily make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using (dependency injection/IOC container) the way I normally do this is by using dependency injection - create a contextviewmodel make it a singleton and then inject it into the constructor of each viewmodel that needs to use it. Therefore it gets created when the app loads, populated when you need it to be populated and then persisted as a context through out the app.

So if you're using DI and an IOC. 
If you're using something like Unity - use the ControlledContainerLifetime() option to make it a singleton.

You'll have to add the contextviewmodel into the container and also (if you're using unity etc - resolve it) so the first time you need it - inject it and update the login property you need. Afterwards - if you need to use it in another view model - just inject it again either with a [Dependency] attribute or into your constructor. Then because the contextviewmodel is a singleton it will contain the same instance of the contextviewmodel with the property previously set. Let me know if you need a code sample.

So long as you inject this view model into any of the other classes you use - you'll be able to use it and it will persist for the lifetime of your app.

Comment: Sounds great.. i also used dependency injection as service agent but i have one question regarding in that what if i want to update that ocontextviewmodel which is initialize once in .